# How can I combine all 3 gyroscope axis to produce 1 int? Xcode Swift Core Motion

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, gyroscope, core-motion

I've followed a few things including Apple's documentation on the core motion. This is probably very simple to do, I just can't put my finger on it. Basically, I'm trying to get all of the X, Y, and Z data, combine it and make it constantly add to the "scoreValue" text. Basically, a constant counter that counts the total degrees rotated ever.

```
    import UIKit
import CoreMotion

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var scoreValue: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var Label: UILabel!
    var motion = CMMotionManager()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        myGyroscope()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        
        
    }

    func myGyroscope() {
        motion.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.1
        motion.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { [self]
            (data, error) in
            print(data as Any)
            if let trueData = data  {
                
                self.view.reloadInputViews()
                
                let x = trueData.rotationRate.x
                let y = trueData.rotationRate.y
                let z = trueData.rotationRate.z
                self.UNDEFINED.text = "\(Double(x).rounded(toPlaces :0))"
                self.UNDEFINED.text = "\(Double(y).rounded(toPlaces :0))"
                self.UNDEFINED.text = "\(Double(z).rounded(toPlaces :0))"
            }
            
        }
        
        return
        
    }

}

extension Double {
    /// Rounds the double to decimal places value
    func rounded(toPlaces places:Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with CoreMotion, but can't you just declare a var in your class and add your x, y, z to that var?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.